# Текст и гиперссылки

Tags: html

```
<a href="https://site.com/">asd</a>
<p>|</p>
<a href="https://site.com/">dsa</a>
```

Как сделать вот так: `asd | dsa` ?

у меня получается

```
asd

|

dsa
```

Comment: оберните в див, и задайте ему display: flex

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Такая разметка - это извращение какое-то. Но всё же:

```css
p {
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<a href="https://site.com/">asd</a>
<p>|</p>
<a href="https://site.com/">dsa</a>
```

Answer (score 3):

Дело в том, что тег `<p>` сам добавляет переходы на новую строку, можно просто не использовать его:

```html
<a href="https://site.com/">asd</a>
|
<a href="https://site.com/">dsa</a>
```

P.S тег `<p>` предназначен для абзацев, лучше в таком случае использовать `<span>` (но он тоже немного для другого). На крайний случай есть элемент `<div>`. Также возможно "отключить" переходы на новую строку у тега `<p>`